# One form for multiple models in Django

Tags: python, django

I must allow user to add city, state and country if it is not already present in the drop-down. Then I must create the respective model instances and then update the city in the userprofile. The below is the working code. I have not checked it for all cases but I have checked it for most cases. Please tell me if there is a better way to achieve the same.

**app_1/models.py**

```
from app_2.models import City

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    website_url = models.URLField(max_length=250, default='http://#')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**app_1/forms.py**

```
from .models import UserProfile
from app_2.models import City, State, Country

class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
website_url = forms.URLField(help_text='http://')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanyProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['logo', 'city', 'website_url', 'location']
```

**app_1/views.py**

```
from app_2.models import City, State, Country

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        up_form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and up_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            if request.POST['input_city']:
                uncommitted_up_form = up_form.save(commit=False)
                co = Country.objects.create(name=request.POST['input_country'])
                st = State.objects.create(country=co, name=request.POST['input_state'])
                cit = City.objects.create(state=st, name=request.POST['input_city'])
                uncommitted_up_form.city = cit
                uncommitted_up_form.save()
            else:
                up_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your profile has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        up_form = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'up_form': up_form
    }
```

**app_1/templates/app_1/profile.html**

```
{% extends 'companies/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                User Info
            </legend>
            {{ u_form|crispy }}
            <label for="id_logo">Logo</label>
            <p>{{ up_form.logo }}</p>
            <label for="id_city">City</label>
            <p>{{ up_form.city }}</p>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleDisplay();">City not present?</a></div><br>
            <div id="hidden_visible_input" style="display: none;">
                <label>City</label>
                <input type="test" name="input_city" required>
                <label>State</label>
                <input type="test" name="input_state" required>
                <label>Country</label>
                <input type="test" name="input_country" required>
            </div><br>
            <label for="id_website_url">Website URL</label>
            <p>{{ up_form.website_url }}</p>
            <label for="id_location">Location</label>
            <p>{{ up_form.location }}</p>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit">
                Update
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const toggleDisplay = () => {
            let hidden_visible = document.getElementById('hidden_visible_input');
            if (hidden_visible.style.display == 'none') {
                hidden_visible.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                hidden_visible.style.display = 'none';
            }
         }
    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

**app_2/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.state.name}'
```

Is there any better way create the `city`, `state` and `country` model instances and then update the userprofile with that value?